# How can I delete every letter in vim

Tags: vim, text-editors, find-and-replace

In my code I have a **HUGE** line containing number and letters.

How can I delete all the letters of this line using vim ?

Answer (score 1):

Place your cursor on the line and type this:

```
:s/\a//g
```

See:

```
:help :substitute
:help /\a
```